# Why i need initialize a varible class when i want use it

Tags: java, eclipse, oop

I have class Book

```
private
Author author;
String title;
int noOfPages;
etc as get/set...
```

class Book extends class Author

```
public String nameOfAuthor;
```

My Question is :
Why do I need to initialize

```
Author author = new Author(); // in private varible of class Book.
```

I'm wondering why I coded in eclipse

```
Author author ; // in private varible of class Book.
```

Eclipse doesn't return any error, but in console it looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Book.setAuthorName(HelloWorld.java:25)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:41)
```

set/get is done. Where is Author's name when I initialize

```
Author author;
```

????

Comment: Why would `Book` extend `Author`? I've never seen a book that has written a book.

Comment: I think you misunderstood a important part of object initialization and the use of constructors in Java.

Comment: thank you all ! i'm newbie of OOP, thank you verry much !

Comment: I initialized Author author; and i done setAuthorName(). isnt author equal null  now? right? or i misunderstood something?

Comment: Read about constructors. Normally you could create constructor, and there pass your values. That is why you need to initialize your class.

Answer (score 2):

A declaration of a field (static or non-static) of a reference type which lacks an initializer is initialized by default with `null`.

It's like if you did:

```
Author author = null;
```

A local variable without initializer is not initialized by default and will yield a compile time error if it used with no value.

Comment: Thanks!
I initialized Author author; and i done setAuthorName(). isnt author equal null  now? right? or i misunderstood something?

Comment: @OneMoreTime if you use `Author author = new Author;` then `author` won't be `null` once it is ued.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object because otherwise variable Author points to nothing or null.

```
// Declare the variable
Author author;
// Create an object (with the new operator) and assign the object to the variable
author = new Author();
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks!
I initialized Author author; and i done setAuthorName(). isnt author equal null  now? right? or i misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an object this way

```
Author a;
```

It is just

```
Author a = null;`
```

Null is an "undefined value". How can you for example get name of nothing? Nothing won't tell you "Hi, my name is NOTHING".

Comment: Thanks!
I initialized Author author; and i done setAuthorName(). isnt author equal null  now? right? or i misunderstood something?